# Compare 2 var incremented by differents loop in a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page which display letters.
In the first part I have the display of letters with a first apex:repeat

In the second part, I display a summary (name of letters) with a second apex:repeat.
In this second part, i have a var (**cnt**) incremented.

I would like know when a letter is on more of 1 page.
So I would like compare my var **cnt** with an other var but i don't know how i can do.
I think at counter(pages) but i don't know how i can do.

So I would like have something like :

```
<p align="center">
            Summary
        </p>
        <br/><br/>
            <apex:repeat value="{!itemWrappers}" var="acc">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!cnt != ???}">
                             <apex:outputText style="font-size:8.5pt;color:red" value="p{!cnt}.....{!acc.item.Name}" /><br/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!cnt == ???}">
                             <apex:outputText style="font-size:8.5pt" value="p{!cnt}.....{!acc.item.Name}" /><br/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
```

If someone can help me.
I suppose i have to put a var in my first part but how can i compare with the good incrementation ?
TY

(sorry for my english)

Comment: In fact,
i would like know how can i have the number of the page.
I would like put in a table the number of the page, after, in my second part, i will compare the value of the table with the value of my counter (cnt)

Comment: with something like it :
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!cnt != cnt.table}">
if it's possible, i don't know if we can have number of page and if we can do it in a table in apex

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to increment an apex:variable within an iteration component.

From the [Salesforce documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_variable.htm):

**Note: apex:variable does not support reassignment inside of an iteration component, such as apex:dataTable or apex:repeat. The result of doing so, e.g., incrementing the  as a counter, is unsupported and undefined.**

I would suggest moving this logic to your controller.

Comment: Hmmm 
my var is just a counter. it indicates me the number of the letter.
it works because i test it
Maybe i didn't understand what you say or i am not really good to explain